# How handle events properly, to avoid having memory leak?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory-leaks

I have an WPF application. That has a memory leak. I have trouble to find exactly the reason.

Tried to use ANTS profiler, and the best thing I have found is

I have an event  `public event Action RegistryPropertyChanged`

And I have lot's of other events, in my code, that are registering to that event.

For Example

```
preferences.RegistryPropertyChanged+= new Action (SetupToolTips);
```

And Some of them are registering in this way

```
preferences.RegistryPropertyChanged += OnMSChanged;
```

Which way it's better, to use, dynamic or static?  Any ideas what can cause the leak?

After I tried to remove all the lines, that are used by **RegistryPropertyChanged** there was no leak. So something is wrong with all this events, but I can't find exactly a reason.Any ideas and help appreciated.Thanks

Comment: http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/02/11/simple-weak-event-listener-for-silverlight/

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx

Comment: What exactly do you see that you consider as a "memory leak"?  Is the application causing memory problems on your system?

Comment: Are the event handlers being attached multiple times without being detached?

Comment: With saying memory leak.. I mean , if I just leave application, in couple hours, memory will growth like 20 MB. I have some timers, that are triggering this events. @Joey I guess they are being attached , without detaching. But the code is really big, and I'm not sure where to detach them.Is it the reason of leak?

Comment: I don't know if it is the reason, it's just a possibility to throw in the mix - I've seen it quite a bit in the code I'm dealing with. The articles Mitch has linked look worth a read.

Comment: Yup. I've been stung by this before in Winforms apps. Redgate have often had good articles about tracing these sorts of problems using their ANTS profiler. Check out http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/learning-memory-management/WPF-silverlight-pitfalls or http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/tracing-memory-leaks-in-.net-applications-with-ants-profiler/

Comment: Thanks to all of you. all the ideas, and links were very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with your objects, ensure that the event is decoupled on dispose.
For example:

```
preferences.RegistryPropertyChanged -= OnMSChanged
```

Also, I had an issue where I had an object which hosted other objects via member references.  If you are working with a lot of objects it is likely that you are not removing the memory reference when you are done with the object.

Just an example but if you have a Car object and it hosts an Engine object, make sure you set the Engine object member reference to NULL when you are done with Car object.
You need to do this because if there is even one reference back to something that is actively used somewhere in your system, these objects will not be disposed because they are "active".

This is all very high level, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WeakEvents.aspx) is a very good post about events, weak events and so on. And [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx) is a good starting point to find your memoryleak.

EDIT: if you want a qiuck and dirty test. take the component which you think is not collected correctly and add this to your component and run your app.

```
 private byte[] myMemoryTest = new byte[300 * 1024 * 1024];    //allocate 300MB
```

if your memory grow in your taskmanager and not fallback you know its not collected the way you want